# What is the int.MaxValue on a 64-bit PC?

Tags: c#, .net, int, int64, int32

```
System.Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue);
```

This line gives me the answer of `2,147,483,647` as I have a 32-bit PC.

Will the answer be same on a 64-bit PC?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes.

> int.MaxValue: 2,147,483,647

Source: https://www.dotnetperls.com/int-maxvalue

Answer (score 56):

**Yes, the answer will be the same on a 64-bit machine.**

In .NET, an `int` is [a signed 32-bit integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx), regardless of the processor.  Its .NET framework type is `System.Int32`.

The [C# Language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx) states:

> The `int` type represents signed 32-bit
>   integers with values between
>   `–2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`.

Answer (score 26):

`int` is just an alias for `Int32` - it's defined in the C# specification. Therefore `int.MaxValue` is the same as `Int32.MaxValue` which will always be 2147483647.

Comment: int.MaxValue is guaranteed to return 2147483647 but no such guarantee for Int32.MaxValue: https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2019/04/08/string-vs-String-is-not-about-style.html