# Value of Mobile Number entered showing "not a valid number" despite putting in regex for 10 digits

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to put in validation for the mobile number entered by the user despite putting in regular expression for 10 digit mobile number.

Here is the Model class

```
 public partial class student1
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Branch { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mobile Number:")]
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile Number is required.")]

        [RegularExpression("^([07][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | 8[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | 9[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Mobile Number.")]
        public Nullable<int> Mobile { get; set; }
    }
```

`Create` view

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

When I run it, for mobile number entered less than 10 it shows the error message that I had written. But for value 10 and greater I get a new message that says

> The value '999999999' is not valid for Mobile Number:.

I don't know where is this message coming from. Also, why isn't it accepting the 10 digit value?

Comment: Pranav Singh is correct about int length in C#, but explain to us how you came up with this regular expression, what do you want the expression of a mobile number to be. To help you more, try and explain each symbol you used to let us know what you were thinking.

Comment: You should not use an `int` (or *any* numeric type) for phone numbers if you care about preserving the leading `0`. Apart from that, phone numbers are often entered using other characters: `+`, `-`, `space`, `(`, `)`. In all applications I have worked with, it is always a string type.

Comment: @PeterB So you mean in database I should change data type to varchar?

Comment: @TasosMoustakas in my country 10 digit mobile numbers are used beginning from 7/8/9 so there's that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Maximum** **value** for `int` in c# for 64 bit machine is

> 2,147,483,647

which is less than 9999999999 so it is overflow for int, so it is error message for model validation from Controller before model binding.

Convert `int` to `long`

```
public Nullable<long> Mobile { get; set; }
```

Also check regular expression, it might miss some valid numbers too.

`int` max value  for c# source:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

[What is the int.MaxValue on a 64-bit PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647427/what-is-the-int-maxvalue-on-a-64-bit-pc)

Comment: Brilliant!!  Thank you sir! :)

Comment: Do I need to change in database as well?

Comment: I used database first approach

Answer (score 1):

try Regular Expression = ^(\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$